# Show rows with a column partially matching a given parameter

Tags: php, mysql, select

Suppose I have a table named `testdb` which has the following values:

```
|       Name       |    Phone   |ID |
|------------------|------------|---|
| supriyo roy      | 9038689236 | 2 |
| supriyo banerjee | 8013147879 | 3 |
| Alex ghosh       | 8985855665 | 4 |
```

Now, I am performing a search by the name and the input given is just "supriyo" (no last name given).
The search result should show both the  values:

```
|       Name       |    Phone   |ID |
|------------------|------------|---|
| supriyo roy      | 9038689236 | 2 |
| supriyo banerjee | 8013147879 | 3 |
```

Is this possible to achieve using MySQL and `php`?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `LIKE`:

```
select *
from your_table
where name like 'supriyo%';
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/LUM78200)

#### Edit:

In php, use:

```
select *
from your_table
where name like '$name%';
```